# Django Database Design - Null for

Tags: django, database-design, null

Say I have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) 
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    postcode = models.IntegerField() 
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3) 
    email = models.EmailField() 
    mobile_phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=12) 
    home_phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True) 
    work_phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True) 
   spouse = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True) 
   children = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Several of the above fields are meant to be optional (e.g. street_address, home_phone_number and work_phone_number, as well as spouse/children).

In Django, for CharField fields, you can set "blank=True" and if the user leaves the form field blank, Django will store a empty string. That's fine.

However, for integer fields like home_phone_number and work_phone_number, this doesn't work - I've had to use "null=True" in order to deal with the case of people not submitting in those details. Is there a better way, model/database design wise to deal with this, and not have NULLs?

Finally, for optional foreign keys like spouse/children (a person may not be married, or may not have any kids), how should you handle those?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) Phone numbers aren't actually integers, they are character strings, and should be stored in the database as such.

(B) Null is basically the correct way to optional foreign keys.

Comment: Adam V: Thanks for your quick response =). Yeah, after reading more, you're absolutely right, phone numbers should be strings, it'd not like I'd be doing mathematical operations on them.

Comment: Adam V: For optional foreign keys - there's really no other way to achieve this, without using NULL? Just curious.